# Directory.EnumerateFiles exception

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a very rare behaviour.

I'm using Windows 10 x64 and Visual Studio 2013 and when I run this code in an 32 bits application

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Windows\System32\winevt").Count()
```

I have an exception of type System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

If I open a non admin cmd console and I run

```
dir C:\Windows\System32\winevt
```

the result is the list of folders in winevt folder. The folder exists and has sub folders.

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Visual Studio is running as administrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In x64 version - all access to System32 redirected to C:\Windows\SystemWOW64.

Try to use this variant to access it:

```
 Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Windows\Sysnative\winevt").Count()
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx explains a lot about the redirector between 32 and 64 bit versions of Windows.